# rails 3 before_update callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with before_update callback

```
def
  if !condition
    #not update record
  end
end
```

I need this not update thing, how to prevent model update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.errors.add(:base, "Some error message")
return false
```

I don't think that before update callbacks are a good place to add validation code. You can do the same with the validates_each.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators). You can't prevent updating a record from a before_update